# Blazed phase profile to generate laguerre gaussian beam

Tags: optics, hologram

How to add blazed grating to a fork grating to achieve maximum diffraction efficiency in the first order while generating laguerre gaussian beam?

Comment: Mathematically? Or literally, how to manufacture it?

Comment: Mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Literally add them: take the the fork grating's phase ($\Phi(r,\theta)=Q\theta$, where *Q* is the order of the Laguerre-Gauss beam) and add it to the blazed grating's phase ($\Phi(x,y)=cx$ (or *cy*), where *c* is a constant depending on the blaze angle). Then take the resulting $\Phi$ modulo $2\pi$, and that's the phase of your grating. Multiply it by $\lambda/2\pi$ to get the height as a function of location on the grating's surface.